# Why I can't define object manager in "__construct" and use it after in other methods (actions)? zf2

Tags: php, orm, constructor, controller, zend-framework2

I started topic on codereview and got nice answer. This answer is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51083/does-my-controller-code-look-good/51089#51089).

All tips are looking nice and now I am trying to follow them in my code.

Author of [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51083/does-my-controller-code-look-good/51089#51089) answer said, that I am getting object manager in all actions (somewhere 2 times). He suggested to do it in `init()` method of my controller and assign object manager to `$this->objectManager`. I tried this:

In that case, that there are no `init()` method in zf2, I used init:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
}
```

On other actions I am using this:

```
public function listAction() { 
    $news = $this->objectManager
        ->getRepository('\News\Entity\Item')
        ->findBy(array(), array('created' => 'DESC'));
    // some more code 
}
```

When I am trying load the page I am getting this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\module\News\src\News\Controller\NewsController.php on line 12
```

Line 12 is a line in `__construct`:

```
$this->objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
```

In old version I was using similar:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    // how I use $objectManager?
    $news = $objectManager
        ->getRepository('\News\Entity\Item')
        ->findBy($options, array('created'=>'DESC'));
    // some more code
}
```

Why approach with `__construct` is not working? What I am doing wrong?

Files on the github:

- [Old and monstrous controller code, but working one](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/developing/module/News/src/News/Controller/NewsController.php)
- [New and pretty controller code, but not working :(](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/testing/module/News/src/News/Controller/NewsController.php)

### Update

File `MODULE/src/MODULE/Factory/NewsControllerFactory.php` contents:

```
<?

namespace News\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use News\Controller\NewsController;



class NewsControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        var_dump("bob");
        $objectManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        return new NewsController($objectManager);
    }
}
```

I tried to `var_dump();` something there and realized, that `createService` function is not called during execution. Why?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204939/zf2-controller-plugin/17208672#17208672 , your problem is similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the service locator has not been set yet. When you're referencing it in your constructor, the $this->getServiceLocator() is still returning null.

If you want to setup objectManager for use in your controller, I'd recommend using a factory. It makes it easier to test your objects;

```
class NewsControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $objectManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        return new NewsController($objectManager);
    }
}
```

and then your controller would look like this

```
class NewsController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct($objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }
}
```

and the necessary addition to your module.config.php

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories'     => array(
        'News\Controller\News' => 'News\Factory\NewsControllerFactory',
    )
)
```

Comment: Where I have to put factory class? `/MODULE/src/MODULE/Factory/NewsControllerFactory.php` will be ok? Or how to name this class better?

Comment: Anyway, now I am getting this: `Missing argument 1 for News\Controller\NewsController::__construct(), called in path\to\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170 and defined in path\to\NewsController.php on line 15`. That means, that `__construct is using somewhere else and it is now working now, because I redifined it.

Comment: Previous problem was solved by passing `$objectManager = null` formal parameter. So, if somewhere it was called, null will be passed as parameter. I updated my question with new code.

Comment: Why id doesn't work? :( I added factory, added it in module.config, updated controller code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why go to such lengths to set the `$this->objectManager`. When a request is made, only one of the `function ....Action()` action is going to be called. So setting it in the `setEventManager()` in the controller will do. This gets called when any action from that controller is requested.

Comment: +1 good answer. Re @KunalDethe Setting the object manager in the `setEventManager`! Seriously? If you need to ask "Why go to such lengths" then I would suggest reading up on [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

Comment: @AlexP good but not working :'( . Why it this doesn't work in my case? I added factory code in update to my question.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav The answer is correct on the DI part, it's wrong in that the factory does not belong in the `service_manager` config, it belongs in `controllers`, like this -> https://gist.github.com/CrispCrumbs/597a1ffc054e1a2041ec

Comment: @Crisp I tried it. Result is [here](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/my-zf2-project/blob/testing/module/News/config/module.config.php#L16-L24). When I am trying to load this action it still [this](http://i.gyazo.com/f1a77da0eaaadd36420b46fa94ab1e83.png) error.

Comment: @Crisp quite rightly spotted the error, the key was wrong. Now (based on your config) **you should rename (`News\Controller\NewsController` to just `News\Controller\News`)**. Currently the service manager cannot find the controller (as it's alias is wrong) so it creates it as an invokable (hence your factory is not called).

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Did you remove the `'News\Controller\Item'` from the list of invokables in module.config.php? Your controllers config should look exactly like the gist I linked - if I'm reading your route configuration and what you're trying to do correctly

Comment: @Crisp Oops. My bad. I really didn't removed `News\Controller\Item` from inovkables. Now I did this and everything is loading fine. Thank you very much :)

Comment: 1 more question is how to name factory better? `NewsFactory`? Or `NewsControllerFactory` is ok? About my last error: I assumed I should only add `factories` and don't need to remove line from `invokables`

Comment: NewsControllerFactory is fine, describes what it does.

Comment: @Crisp I tried to improve my code and separated `index` and `category` controller. Now I am getting redirected to `zfcadmin`, instead of loading `news/category`. Can this redirect be caused by editions, linked with this answer (using factory instead of invokables)?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav it's unlikely, more likely a route config issue. Maybe try disabling zfcadmin and see if that shows up the problem?

Comment: @Crisp :) I understood what causes problem earlier, but it worked. New action `category` was not specifeid in BjyAuthorize config.

Answer (score -2):

This should work -

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

    protected $objectManager;

    public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events) {
        parent::setEventManager($events);

        $this->objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    }
    [......]
}`
```

Then just use `$this->objectManager` in any actions or simple functions in that whole controller -

```
public function listAction() { 
    $news = $this->objectManager
        ->getRepository('\News\Entity\Item')
        ->findBy(array(), array('created' => 'DESC'));
    // some more code 
}
```

Comment: This actually works, not sure why this answer received so much negativity.

Comment: Because ZF2 has a concept of `dependency injection` in which the object of the required service needs to be passed to the class that wants to use it. In this case, the controller does have a `service locator` available directly and so in the `construct` of the controller the `object manager` could be managed by `set` and `get` functions or using the `Factory` approach for controllers to have the dependencies injected already. After a long time of coding, I have understood that the `Factory` approach is the better way in ZF2.

Comment: The controller doesn't seem to have the service locator available directly, unless a Factory is used, or am I wrong? Unless there is a clear downside to using setEventManager(), I don't see why this is so terrible, when creating factories requires modifying three different files. Probably using a Factory is more ZF2ish though.

Comment: The `Controller` does have the access to the `Service Manager` directly and also the `Factory` is more ZF2ish (very true). But for the downside of the `setEventManager()`... will find the exact reason and be back.