# Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for translate

Tags: zend-framework2

I have written a controller plugin to get the MVC translator using ZF 2.5.

Here is my translate controller plugin

```
namespace Freedom\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;

/**
 * Translate
 *
 */
class Translate extends AbstractPlugin
{

    /**
     *
     * @var Translator
     */
    private $translator;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * Translate message
     * @param string $message
     * @param string $textDomain
     * @param string $locale
     * @return string
     */
    public function __invoke($message, $textDomain = 'default', $locale = null)
    {
        return $this->translator->translate($message, $textDomain, $locale);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Translator
     */
    function getTranslator()
    {
        return $this->translator;
    }

}
```

and is factory

```
namespace Freedom\Controller\Plugin\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Freedom\Controller\Plugin\Translate;

/**
 * TranslateFactory
 *
 */
class TranslateFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new Translate($container->get('translator'));
    }

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $container)
    {
        return $this($container->getServiceLocator(), Translate::class);
    }
}
```

and finally in my module.config

```
'controller_plugins' => [
    'factories' => [
        'checkRedirect' => 'Freedom\Controller\Plugin\Service\CheckRedirectFactory',
        'translate' => 'Freedom\Controller\Plugin\Service\TranslateFactory',
    ],
],
```

The problem I have is that I am getting this error and I can't understand why.

```
Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for translate
```

As you can see I have registered the plugin in my module.config but the plugin manager can't find it. I have checked that the controller_plugins key exists in the config and that my namespacing is correct.  I also have another plugin called checkRedirect that produces the same error.

I simply can't figure out what is going on, please can someone tell me what I have missed, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem, I was calling the plugin from the [controllers constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204939/zf2-controller-plugin/17208672#17208672) which does not work.  Calling from an action, everything ok.

Answer (score 0):

please try this, may be it help you.

I think all is ok, but you need to update this,

```
'controller_plugins' => [
    'factories' => [
        'checkRedirectPlugin' => 'Freedom\Controller\Plugin\Service\CheckRedirectFactory',
        'translatePlugin' => 'Freedom\Controller\Plugin\Service\TranslateFactory',
    ],
   'aliases' =>[
       'checkRedirect' => 'checkRedirectPlugin',
        'translate' => 'translatePlugin'
    ]

],
```

now use aliases, you can now access from your controller as,

```
$this->translate()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I finally found the problem, please see my answer.